# Read binary file with Karma-Jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm developing a test plateforme and i want to test a file uploading service.
Is there any way to read a binary file and append it to the FormData

```
var file = someModule.readFile('test-data/roof-top.tif');

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file',file, 'uploadedFile');
```

or maybe i should build a static file server and do some Ajax calls to retrieve my binary files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try encoding your binary data as text (base64, or array of bytes). You can then load that in the browser as a javascript file like you would for any other test data.

Other than this, setting up a file server is probably the way to go. You can actually get [Karma to serve static files](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/files.html) to you wouldn't need to set up a server yourself.

Comment: thanks a lot that was very helpful.
I configured karma to serve static files

Answer (score 0):

You will need node's [FileSystem](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to read file, then create [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) which is native JS object and then append file to FormData

The following scenario would result in something like that:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var formData = new FormData();

fs.readFile('test-data/roof-top.tif', function(err, data){

    var blob = new Blob(data);
    formData.append('file', blob, 'uploadedFile');

});
```

Comment: I can't use fs in a client side testing code, Jasmine code is executed in the Browser

Comment: I thought you are doing that in node.js. You can not open files from JS script without user selecting a file for upload.

Comment: I think i'm gonna create a simple file server and than make some Blob object from Ajax response